# Suppress 'Warning: no access to tty' in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, tcsh, tty

I have a short simple script, that compiles a `.c` file and runs it on a remote server running `tcsh` and then just gives back control to my machine (this is for school, I need my programs to work properly on the lab computers but want to edit them etc. on my machine). It runs commands this way:

```
ssh -T user@server << EOF
cd cs4400/$dest
gcc -o $efile $file
./$efile
EOF
```

So far it works fine, but it gives this warning every time I do this:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

I know this technically isn't a problem, but it's SUPER annoying. I'm trying to do school work, checking the output of my program etc., and this clutters everything, and I HATE it.

I'm running this version of ssh on my machine:

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

This version of tcsh on the server:

```
tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux)
```

And this version of ssh on the server:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
```

Comment: The `-T` explicitly *disables* tty allocation, I'm pretty sure you want `-t` to explicitly *enable* tty allocation and get rid of your error.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have remembered to say something about this. I had been doing that before trying to solve a different problem, and here's what changing that gives: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` which is given _in addition_ to the warnings I previously had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is actually printed by shell, in this case tcsh.
You can use

```
strings  /usr/bin/tcsh | grep 'no access to tty'
```

to ensure that it belongs to `tcsh` itself.

It is related to ssh only very loosely, ie `ssh` in this case is just the trigger, not the cause.

You should either change your approach and not use `HERE DOCUMENT`. Instead place executable custom_script into `/path/custom_script` and run it via ssh.

```
# this will work
ssh user@dest '/path/custom_script'
```

Or, just run complex command as a oneliner.

```
# this will work as well
ssh user@dest "cd cs4400/$dest;gcc -o $efile $file;./$efile"
```

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, I solved a similar problem (for script provisioning on Vagrant) with `ssh -t -t` (note that `-t` comes twice).
Advice based on the ssh BSD man page:

> -T      Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.
>
> -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can
>   be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Answer (score 0):

If running `tcsh` is not important for you, specify a different shell and it will work:

```
ssh -T user@server bash << EOF
cd cs4400/$dest
gcc -o $efile $file
./$efile
EOF
```